# Multiple String in a single class? i think

Tags: java, string, class

I'm having a real problem with this. Started with just Gradebook courseName. and had a setName and getName working np. Then the book told me to add in an instructor string also. but i just can't get it to work, i've spent 3 days on it now :\ can you help

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class GradeBook
{

    private String courseName;
    private String intstructorName;

    private GradeBook (String startCourseName, String startInstructorName); 
        courseName = startCourseName;
        intructorName = startInstructorName;
    }

    public void GradeBook( String name ) {
        courseName = name; 
    }

    public void GradeBook( String nameValue ) {
        instructorName = name; 
    }

    public void setCourseName( String name ) {
        CourseName = name;
    }

    public void setInstructorName( String nameValue ) {
        InstructorName = name;
    }

    public void getCourseName( String name )
    {
        return courseName;
    }

    public void getInstructorName ( String nameValue )
    {
        return instructorName;
    }

    public void displayMessage();
    {
        System.out.printf( "Welcome to the grade book for\n%s!\n\n",
            getCourseName() );
        System.out.printf( "Your instructor for this course is\n%s!\n\n",
            getinstructorName() );
    }

}
```

Here's the errors

```
C:\Users\Tony Q\Downloads>Javac GradeBook.java
GradeBook.java:9: error: ';' expected
        public GradeBook(String startCourseName, String startInstructorName)
                                                                            ^
GradeBook.java:11: error: <identifier> expected
                instructorName = startInstructorName;
                              ^
GradeBook.java:14: error: class, interface, or enum expected
        public void GradeBook( String name ) {
               ^
GradeBook.java:16: error: class, interface, or enum expected
        }
        ^
GradeBook.java:18: error: class, interface, or enum expected
        public void GradeBook( String nameValue ) {
               ^
GradeBook.java:20: error: class, interface, or enum expected
        }
        ^
GradeBook.java:22: error: class, interface, or enum expected
        public void setCourseName( String name ) {
               ^
GradeBook.java:24: error: class, interface, or enum expected
        }
        ^
GradeBook.java:26: error: class, interface, or enum expected
        public void setInstructorName( String nameValue ) {
               ^
GradeBook.java:28: error: class, interface, or enum expected
        }
        ^
GradeBook.java:30: error: class, interface, or enum expected
        public void getCourseName( String name )
               ^
GradeBook.java:33: error: class, interface, or enum expected
        }
        ^
GradeBook.java:35: error: class, interface, or enum expected
        public void getInstructorName ( String nameValue )
               ^
GradeBook.java:38: error: class, interface, or enum expected
        }
        ^
GradeBook.java:40: error: class, interface, or enum expected
        public void displayMessage()
               ^
GradeBook.java:44: error: class, interface, or enum expected
                System.out.printf( "Your instructor for this course is\n%s!\n\n"
,
                ^
GradeBook.java:46: error: class, interface, or enum expected
        }
        ^
17 errors
```

Comment: `"but i just can't get it to work"` -- doesn't tell us what the problem is.

Comment: You did misspell `intstructor`.

Comment: intructorName - intstructorName - InstructorName - instructorName - These are all different.

Comment: If you haven't gathered, it's _extremely_ helpful to post the error message(s) you're getting.

Comment: Jeez, there are over dozen errors. Don't treat us like a Compiler.

Comment: Sure no problem, i just need to find a way of writing the errors into here

Comment: There is [[edit]] button under your question. Use it and add your your errors.

Comment: PShemo, how can i copy all the errors from compiler (it's command prompt) is there a way?

Comment: If you are using Windows console you can right click it, select all, mark text you want to copy and press enter (yes when text is selected enter will do normal ctrl+c stuff).

Comment: I would definitely suggest using an IDE like [Eclipse](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/) or [NetBeans](https://netbeans.org/downloads/) (just download something for Java SE) to help with some of these issues while you are a beginner.  It will give you a lot of hints when you make typos, it will show you (usually) exactly where a problem exists, and it will give you a console window that is easy to copy your compiler errors from so our feathers don't get ruffled ;)  It's good to know you're trying, but half the work (and fun!) of programming is tackling issues you don't know where to start on.

Comment: Yeah, i've been trying to learn for a while now and im really getting disheartened that i can't fix the problems myself like i could earlier on with the smaller programs. :\

Comment: I think what i'll do is start the chapter again re: classes, as i'ts clear im not understanding the syntax - i installed Netbeans now tho!

Answer (score 2):

You have an extra semicolon after the declaration of your constructor.  Remove it.

```
private GradeBook (String startCourseName, String startInstructorName)  // from here
```

You will need an opening brace `{` instead.

The semicolon should be fixed on the `displayMessage` method also.

Also, more than likely, the constructor should be `public` so it's accessible from outside of the class.

Additionally, the instructor name variable is misspelled in declaration and usage: `intstructorName` should be `instructorName`, and `intructorName = startInstructorName;` in the constructor should be `instructorName = startInstructorName;`, although if they were misspelled the same way it would be legal.

Other misspellings of variable names exist in `setCourseName` and `setInstructorName`.

You are attempting to return something from `void getInstructorName`.  Declare it to return `String` instead.

You have two overloaded constructors that take exactly one `String`; having two constructors (or two methods) with the same name and signature (parameter name doesn't matter) is illegal.  I think you only need one of them.

Comment: Done thanks. Anything else? im getting 18 errors

Comment: All those errors and you couldn't even list one of them...

Comment: Ok cool, because like 15 of the error's are pointing to the "voids" in every line

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `;` here. You need an opening `{` brace there.

```
public GradeBook (String startCourseName, String startInstructorName) { // ;
```

Same with `displayMessage()` except it already has the brace below

```
public void displayMessage() // ;
```

Comment: ok the errors im getting are :   ; expected, after (startxx, xxx). error: class, interface , or enum expected public void GradeBook( string name ) and lots more the same, it's pointing to the VOID in every line

Answer (score 1):

Is it just that you spelled "instructor" wrong in: `private String intstructorName;` ?

Comment: ok i fixed that, still 18 errors

Comment: Highlight Errors > Right Click > Copy > Stack Overflow > Right Click > Paste

Answer (score 1):

There is many, many, many mistakes which makes this code unable even to build and run, not mention to do what you want...

You should use IDE like netbeans, which tells you, what is wrong with your synthax.

The working code should be something like this :

```
public class GradeBook {

    private String courseName;
    private String intstructorName;

    public GradeBook(String courseName, String instructorName) {
        this.courseName = courseName;
        this.intstructorName = instructorName;
    }

    public void displayMessage()
    {
        System.out.printf("Welcome to the grade book for\n%s!\n\n",
                this.getCourseName());
        System.out.printf("Your instructor for this course is\n%s!\n\n",
                this.getIntstructorName());
    }

    /**
     * @return the courseName
     */
    public String getCourseName() {
        return courseName;
    }

    /**
     * @param courseName the courseName to set
     */
    public void setCourseName(String courseName) {
        this.courseName = courseName;
    }

    /**
     * @return the intstructorName
     */
    public String getIntstructorName() {
        return intstructorName;
    }

    /**
     * @param intstructorName the intstructorName to set
     */
    public void setIntstructorName(String intstructorName) {
        this.intstructorName = intstructorName;
    }
}
```

Comment: thats great! the problem is the book shows me how to do a basic class with set and get and uses string. then it says "now add another string call instructor and rewrite the program" and this is only the second chapter, and there's NO solution to it

Comment: Hi im using netbeans now, i typed everything in correctly now but i can compile or run, everything is greyed out under "run".. everything.

Comment: To "run" something, you have to create new project with "main" method. You cant run classes itself, because there is nothing to run.